# How to choice the right memory when making an EC2 instance for xampp crud app

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, xampp

I'm working on php project with mysql and xampp, the purpose of this app will be database operations(like insert/update/view/delete) and i want to host this on web. Also i have a little GUI to help the user make the operationsv.

I found that AWS EC2 is a good choice but i dont know how should i choose best specifications for this instance to have an idea for the price? How many memory i need just for those operations?

Comment: We can't tell you what your requirements are, you need to measure the resources that your application requires.

Comment: In general, pick a small size and monitor it to see if it is too small! Keep an eye on CPU Utilization metrics and the performance of your application. If you are simply wanting a single instance for a little app, consider using Amazon Lightsail -- it is a "cut-down" version of EC2 and is cheaper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should evaluate the most important performance metrics first for your application and decide accordingly which EC2 instance type to choose from.

For applications that benefit from a low cost per CPU, you should try compute-optimized instances (C1 or CC2) first.

For applications that require the lowest cost per GiB of memory, It is recommended to use memory-optimized instances (M2 or CR1).

I would recommend you to use AWS RDS service for database instead of installing MySQL on EC2 instance.

For more details https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/choosing-the-right-ec2-instance-type-for-your-application/

Comment: but can i have some html and css with aws rds? i want to have a gui to help making those operations

Comment: @Vishal  If you would not install MySQL on EC2, what would you use for a database manager?

Comment: @WilsonHauck You can use AWS RDS service specifically made available for database management.